# Cannot load view from HMVC/Modules Codeigniter4

Tags: php, hmvc, codeigniter-4

### When I load view from App/Views it's worked but when it's from modules folder it's failed

My autoload

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Modules'     => ROOTPATH . 'modules',
];
```

My Controller

```
<?php namespace Modules\Assets\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
class AssetsControl extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Modules/Assets/Views/index'); // failed
        return view('Views/welcome_message'); // Success
    }
}
?>
```

Folder Structures

```
 1. app
 2. modules
    - Assets
        + Config
        + Controllers
        + Models
        + Views
 3. public
 4. test
```

Error message from CI4
[image: Error message CI4]

Comment: Please share all error messages in text form, along with the attempts to resolve them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to use namespaces when calling the views

So Your line

```
return view('Modules/Assets/Views/index'); // failed
```

Should be

```
return view('Modules\Assets\Views\index'); // ??
```